# Invoke-WebRequest in Dockerfile is failing with error

Tags: powershell, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have Dockerfile and one of the command in that file is:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.4.0/node-v18.4.0-x64.msi" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "node-v18.4.0-x64.msi"
```

When I execute this command alone directly in PowerShell it's working fine without any issues, but it's throwing error while building the Dockerfile.
Error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Removing intermediate container 97fca3fc2976
The command 'cmd /S /C [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 
[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;   Invoke-WebRequest "https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.4.0/node-v18.4.0-x64.msi"   -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "node-v18.4.0-x64.msi"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I'm not understanding what could be wrong here. I even tried by specifying the full relative path in -OutFile option, still didn't work.
Any suggestion to resolve this issue?